# Dynamic Link inside PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have been toying around with the idea where I echo a link and it changes based on the string I got from my database. (the GET command)

Here is the code I been working with:

```
<?php echo '<a href="submittoplay.php?username="' . ($username) . ">";?>
```

I want the output of the echo to appear like so, where `$username = bob`

`<a href="submittoplay.php?username=bob` or in the address bar when I click on the link to be `submittoplay.php?username=bob`

But when I run the code only`"<a href="submittoplay.php?=username"` shows. It doesnt seem to want to take my string that I had gathered from the database and plug it into the echoed link.

I know $username is a valid string, I tested it and do get the result I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that `$username` contains a string and isn't merely empty?

Comment: Right before you echo your statement add var_dump($username); It will show an empty variable.

Comment: Yes, I had tested username and it does return a valid string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it goes :--

```
$username='bob';
echo '<a href="submittoplay.php?user='.$username . '">User link</a>';
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me :/ getting echo of nothing

Comment: How is this possible that it does not echo anything. Worked perfectly when i tried.

Comment: Yeah my bad I had it working the whole time I just didnt update it on my server via FTP. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

inside php

```
$user_name='sample';
echo '<a href="submittoplay.php?user='.$user_name. '">Your link</a>';
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8c4-ag5)**

Outside Php

```
<a href="submittoplay.php?user=<?php echo $user_name;?>">Your link</a>
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9kr-vzw)**